# Проблема с Math.pow()

Tags: java

Пишу

```
long i = (long) (Math.pow(2, 30));
i*=100000;
System.out.print(i);
```

Выводит 0.
Это шо такое и почему? Я думал просто вылетит исключение, а может быть и ответ, но этого я никак не ожидал. Почему так?

Comment: https://ideone.com/i3UEz4

Comment: 107374182400000

Comment: Все. Понял ошибку. Здесь я написал Math.pow в скобочках, а в коде без. Благодарю.

Comment: не знал, что это так важно)

Comment: В скобках или без - разницы нет.

Comment: int gg = (int) Math.pow(2, 30);
        gg*=100000;
        System.out.print(gg);

Comment: это выводит 0..

Comment: Вы не видите разницы между int и long?

Comment: так стоп.. что то я не понял

Comment: я ожидал, что с int программа выбросит исключение

Comment: ладно. вроде разобрался